# Switch type for low voltage D.C. Motor

Tags: switches

Just an art project with a D.C. Motor running at 5 volts. I'm interested in the aesthetics of the switch and am looking for something vintage in look. Question: what types of switches can I get away with/search for? Will most anything that completes a circuit between two wires suffice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer the second question, almost certainly yes. Do you have any information about the current rating of the motor?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go something REALLY old school, and since you are using low voltages perhaps a [knife switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017W6F0O) takes your fancy.

[image]

Comment: For makers of Frankensteins monsters and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing that we are talking about that small motors with low current ratings, practically any switch can do the job. Google for "vintage switch" you will find some very nice (and aesthetics) switches, like this one:

[image]

Side note: Old switches, especially those that were used to drive tubes and big motors, tend to be **very** robust in terms of current ratings.